# Alternative way to get response from a database in node js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Im using MySql to store data from a node.js server

All the responses from a Query sent through node.js Conection.Query function is recieved through a callback function...

I was wondering if this is because is MySql...

is there any alternative for databases to get an answer immediately?

for example, this is the standard way im doing it now.

```
Self.Conection.query(Query, function(err, result) {
    //handling result here
    });
```

Is there any way to achieve the next example?

```
var response=Query("select * from table");
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with MySQL, it's a node.js issue. It will depend on if the code is server side or client side.

Comment: ok, but is there a way? to achived this on the server side?

Comment: From, what a quick search showed, I think this is just the way node.js works.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/1687

use mysql2, after connection

```
const [rows, fields] = await connection.execute('SELECT * FROM `table`);
```

}